Neo4J - Is there a setting to decrease the spacing between node clusters in NeoDash?
I don't know if I'm just looking in the wrong place, but I can't find any settings to make a graph with several separate clusters look less spread out. I am using the force-based layout.
I know there's a setting to change the tree layout level distance, but I'm not using the tree layout, so changing that setting didn't do anything for me.
